# Can one say "depends how you take it" to express "depends on your view"?

Tags: modal-verbs, phrases

Is there a phrase ***to take it*** **[somehow]** which says something like *to interpret it/utilize some information in one's own way*?

I have found 1 [mention](http://www.danielpipes.org/comments/160579) of the phrase about which I'm not sure if it is correctly expressing what I mean.

Comment: Are you asking if "to take something" is right? if so, "depends on how you take it" means it depends on how you think about it and is very a common construction.

Comment: Please see the definition B2 on this: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/take

Comment: @Cardinal Thanks, I wasn't sure whether it is an actual phrase in English as well.